# NSMutablearray removeallobjects crash my app. Works fine in NSZombie

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

This is how i declare my `NSMutablearray`

```
 self.otherDealsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I'll get some values from a webservice and insert it into this array. This mutable array is used to populate my tableview data. But when user clicks a button, I want to get new data from the webservice and insert it back to the mutable array.

During the process of replacing the content of the mutable array,  if the user clicks or scrolls the tableview, the app will crash. So to avoid this, I tried to empty the table view first by emptying the mutable array and reload the table. This is my code to make the array empty

```
if ([self.otherDealsList count] > 0) {

                [self.otherDealsList removeAllObjects];
                [tableView reloadData];
            }
```

But my app keeps crashing (`"Bad access"`) when it run on `'removeallobjects'` line. I'm pretty sure I didn't release it anywhere.

I also tried to run it using NSZombie thingy. But it won't crash at all.

Comment: Please post the code where you get the values and insert them into the array. That is most likely where the problem lies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray removeAllObjects crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175573/nsmutablearray-removeallobjects-crash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am linking you another SO question very similar to yours. You are most likely releasing some objects in the NSMutableArray before calling removeAllObjects and that is what is causing your problem. Please read more here - [NSMutableArray removeAllObjects crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175573/nsmutablearray-removeallobjects-crash).

Comment: U gave me the idea actually. When I check on my class which contain the data in that mutablearray, I noticed my [super dealloc] is on top. It should be at the bottom of the dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be retaining your object an extra time.

```
self.otherDealsList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Retaining an object an extra time will not cause a BAD EXEC access error, it will lead to memory leaks.